# The {{key}} interpolation syntax in I18n messages is deprecated. Please use %{key} instead

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I am running ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [i686-darwin10.3.2] with Rails 2.3.8 and I have to use that version. When I run 'rake test' I get

```
The {{key}} interpolation syntax in I18n messages is deprecated. Please use %{key} instead.
```

There was a bug but now should be solved: https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/4525-favor-in-all-code-instead-of-deprecated-as-interpolation-syntax-for-i18n

I have tried i18n gem with versions 0.4.1, 0.4.0 and 0.4.0-beta1 without luck

Any idea?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I downgraded i18n to 0.3.7 to get rid of the error. [Apparently](http://groups.google.com.au/group/formtastic/msg/010fd549e5c31766) you can also install i18n from its rails3 branch (should work on 2.3.8 as well).

Comment: didn't work. Activesupport has a vendored version 0.4.1 within it and it loads it in addition to 0.3.7

Answer (score 1):

Yo need to uninstall the most early version or  you can 
set this line on environment.rb

config.gem 'i18n', :version => '~> 0.3.7'

and them run rake gems:unpack and the gem will be unpack on your vendor folder